# How to compare pandas DataFrame against None in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.x, nonetype

How do I compare a pandas DataFrame with `None`? I have a constructor that takes one of a `parameter_file` or a `pandas_df` but never both.

```
def __init__(self,copasi_file,row_to_insert=0,parameter_file=None,pandas_df=None):
    self.copasi_file=copasi_file
    self.parameter_file=parameter_file
    self.pandas_df=pandas_df
```

However, when I later try to compare the `pandas_df` against `None`, (i.e. when `self.pandas_df` actually contains a pandas dataframe):

```
    if self.pandas_df!=None:
        print 'Do stuff'
```

I get the following TypeError:

```
  File "C:\Anaconda1\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 885, in eval
    % repr(other))

TypeError: Could not compare [None] with block values
```

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Use `is not`:

```
if self.pandas_df is not None:
    print 'Do stuff'
```

[PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) says:

> Comparisons to singletons like `None` should always be done with `is` or `is not`, never the equality operators.

There is also a nice [explanation](http://jaredgrubb.blogspot.de/2009/04/python-is-none-vs-none.html) why.